# Xamarin Forms masterdetail hide backbutton

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, shared, master-detail

I am working on Xamarin forms shared project with a master detail page.  When I run the app the master detail page is the first item that loads yet it shows the back button which once clicked opens the navigation (master) drawer.  This makes no navigation sense whatsoever!  I have tried to hide the back button but have not been able to do this.  Has anyone come across this and succeeded in doing this?  I would prefer a programmatical solution rather than a xaml one.

I have tried adding the below code:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
```

But this doesn't work.  I want to keep the toolbar as I will be adding my own menu items here but want the back button gone.

Comment: please can you mark my post as the correct answer for this question? Its a StackOverflow practice. Really appreciate

Comment: I haven't marked it as the right answer because it isn't the right answer. Tried the code you gave and back button is still showing!

Comment: Can you send me that code?

Comment: what is the answer of it. Is there any one who got its correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, string.Empty);
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
```